# How to code an Android app that use Sony Dualshock 4 controller digital and analogs inputs?

Tags: java, android, gamepad

I created an Android app with java to control my robot via bluetooth, however I need a more advanced way to interact with my robot rather than using virtual joystick and virtual buttons on my phone or tablet. I have a Sony Dualshock 4 Controller that I want to use to control my robot via my java android app.

So, I searched ways to listen to events for digital and analog input of my controller by using USB OTG (usb cable).

I saw that the native KeyEvent can work but only with digital input. For exemple this [KeyEvent constant](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_X)

I saw also a library called [Gamepad4j](https://github.com/marcelschoen/gamepad4j) but I didn't manage to use it and it didn't fit my requirements in terms of android version.

So I want a way to listen for analog events (like joysticks moves) and digital event (like a button pressed on the controller) in Java on my android device on android API 25 (Android 7.1.1 Nougat) or if it's not possible, on API 28 (Android 9.0 Pie). What are the best approches ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a game controller can be handled alike any other `InputDevice` ...

It's either `InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD` or `InputDevice.SOURCE_JOYSTICK`.

the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/controller-input.html) also shows this:

[image: Figure 1 shows how Android maps key codes and axis values to the physical controls on most game controllers.]

where 1 are the digital buttons:

`AXIS_HAT_X`, `AXIS_HAT_Y`, `DPAD_UP`, `DPAD_DOWN`, `DPAD_LEFT`, `DPAD_RIGHT`.

and 2/3 are the analog joysticks:

`AXIS_X`, `AXIS_Y`, `BUTTON_THUMBL`

`AXIS_Z`, `AXIS_RZ`, `BUTTON_THUMBR`

Comment: Thanks you! This answer helped me a lot! https://github.com/lefuturiste/LYRC-control-android-app/commit/9c7f83f25429dc134569d2d809dcd6e742cf0318